# sed recipe: how to do stuff between two patterns that can be either on one line or on two lines?

Tags: sed

Let's say we want to do some substitutions only between some patterns, let them be `<a>` and `</a>` for clarity... (*all right, all right, they're `start` and `end`!.. Jeez!*)

So I know what to do if `start` and `end` always occur on the same line: just design a proper regex.

I also know what to do if they're guaranteed to be on different lines and I don't care about anything in the line containing `end` and I'm also OK with applying all the commands in the line containing `start` **before** `start`: just specify the address range as `/start/,/end/`.

This, however, doesn't sound very useful. What if I need to do a smarter job, for instance, introduce changes inside a `{...}` block?

One thing I can think of is breaking the input on `{` and `}` before processing and putting it back together afterwards:

```
sed 's/{\|}/\n/g' input | sed 'main stuff' | sed ':a $!{N;ba}; s/\n\(}\|{\)\n/\1/g'
```

Another option is the opposite:

```
cat input | tr '\n' '#' | sed 'whatever; s/#/\n/g'
```

Both of these are ugly, mainly because the operations are not confined within a single command. The second one is even worse because one has to use some character or substring as a "newline holder" assuming it isn't present in the original text.

So the question is: are there better ways or can the above-mentioned ones be optimized? This is quite a regular task from what I read in recent SO questions, so I'd like to choose the best practice once and for all.

P.S. I'm mostly interested in pure `sed` solutions: can the job be do with one invocation of `sed` and nothing else? Please no `awk`, `Perl`, etc.: this is more of a theoretical question, not a "need the job done asap" one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
# create multiline test data
cat <<\! >/tmp/a
> this
> this { this needs
> changing to
> that } that
> that
> !
sed '/{/!b;:a;/}/!{$q;N;ba};h;s/[^{]*{//;s/}.*//;s/this\|that/\U&/g;x;G;s/{[^}]*}\([^\n]*\)\n\(.*\)/{\2}\1/' /tmp/a
this
this { THIS needs
changing to
THAT } that
that
# convert multiline test data to a single line
tr '\n' ' ' </tmp/a >/tmp/b
sed '/{/!b;:a;/}/!{$q;N;ba};h;s/[^{]*{//;s/}.*//;s/this\|that/\U&/g;x;G;s/{[^}]*}\([^\n]*\)\n\(.*\)/{\2}\1/' /tmp/b
this this { THIS needs changing to THAT } that that
```

Explanation:

- Read the data into the pattern space (PS). `/{/!b;:a;/}/!{$q;N;ba}`
- Copy the data into the hold space (HS). `h`
- Strip non-data from front and back of string. `s/[^{]*{//;s/}.*//`
- Convert data e.g. `s/this\|that/\U&/g`
- Swap to HS and append converted data. `x;G`
- Replace old data with converted data.`s/{[^}]*}\([^\n]*\)\n\(.*\)/{\2}\1/`

EDIT:

A more complicated answer which I think caters for more than one block per line.

```
# slurp file into pattern space (PS)
:a
$! {
N
ba
}
# check for presence of \v if so quit with exit value 1
/\v/q1
# replace original newlines with \v's
y/\n/\v/
# append a newline to PS as a delimiter
G
# copy PS to hold space (HS)
h
# starting from right to left delete everything but blocks
:b
s/\(.*\)\({.*}\).*\n/\1\n\2/
tb
# delete any non-block details form the start of the file
s/.*\n//
# PS contains only block details
# do any block processing here e.g. uppercase this and that
s/th\(is\|at\)/\U&/g
# append ps to hs
H
# swap to HS
x
# replace each original block with its processed one from right to left
:c
s/\(.*\){.*}\(.*\)\n\n\(.*\)\({.*}\)/\1\n\n\4\2\3/
tc
# delete newlines
s/\n//g
# restore original newlines
y/\v/\n/
# done!
```

N.B. This uses GNU specific options but could be tweaked to work with generic sed's.

Comment: Nice approach, but it seems to have a problem, e.g. with this input: `this \n this that \n this {this is OK} that {this \n must be changed to that \n and that} and that \n {and that \n } \n '`

Comment: Namely, I think it doesn't cope with more than one block per line.

Comment: This works! Wow, this is complex. My only concern is this `\v` thing. Is this vertical tab? What are the chances of this occuring in the input? As stated in the question, I don't feel good about replacing newlines with something, but maybe it's safe with a special character like this?

Comment: @LevLevitsky `\v` can be any unique character or combination of characters e.g. `s/\n/*NEWLINE*/g ....s/\*NEWLINE\*/\n/g`. N.B. there is a test beforehand for this unique character(s) which leaves the file unprocessed but with a non-zero exit code. `/\*NEWLINE\*/q1`

Comment: I get that, but the question is, is there a character I can use to be 100% sure it won't occur in the input. So that I don't have to find it by trial and error every time, you know.